# getElementById another page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, getelementbyid

Is it possible to use a getElementById but from another page?

I have a button function on a "page 1" but then I try to iframe "page 1" to "page 2" the button would not work. I tried long and hard to fix this issue but would not find a solution except for maybe trying to use a getElementById from "page 1" and put it into "page 2"

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "iframe page 1 to page 2"? Do you mean to say that you have a webpage containing an iframe, containing a button?

Comment: You need to get hold of the window.document object of that frame.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use an external javascript file for getting the elements using getElementById(), and include it in the page2.

Answer (score 0):

`contentDocument` is what I think you are missing.

**page1.htm**

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function buttonFunction()
   { document.getElementById("myFrame").contentDocument.getElementById("page2Elem").innerHTML="From Page 1";
   };
  function page2Function()
   { alert("Page 2 caused this alert!");
   };
 </script>
 <body>
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="buttonFunction();">
  <br>
  <iframe id="myFrame" src="page2.htm"></iframe>
  <div id="fromPage2">no messages</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**page2.htm**

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function callPage1()
   { window.parent.document.getElementById('fromPage2').innerHTML='Hello from page 2';
     window.parent.page2Function();
   };
 </script>
 <body>
  <div id="page2Elem">Page 2 Element</div>
  <input type="button" value="Call Page 1" onclick="callPage1();">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want a function from page 2 to work on page 1 (in your example). There is a button in page 2 that does not work when I iframe to page 1 so i thought if i can just add that button to page 1 it may work.

Comment: Updated so that action can affect both pages from the other.

Comment: Edited again so that page2.htm calls a 'function()' on page 1.